# Why is my testlink install experiencing this MySQL error?

Tags: mysql, testlink

I have configured the testlink on my local machine. Everything is working fine expect while selecting "Requirements based Report" from "Result" menu it showing the following `DB Access Error`.

```
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 

 ============================================================================== 

#0  database->exec_query(SELECT id FROM xp_executions WHERE  tcversion_id=(SELECT id FROM xp_nodes_hierarchy  WHERE parent_id='0') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1, -1) called at [D:\wamp\www\testlink\lib\functions\database.class.php:535]
#1  database->fetchRowsIntoMap(SELECT id FROM xp_executions WHERE  tcversion_id=(SELECT id FROM xp_nodes_hierarchy  WHERE parent_id='0') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1, id, 1) called at [D:\wamp\www\testlink\lib\results\resultsReqs.php:103]

 ==============================================================================
```

I have searched on google regarding `DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START` error but didn't found any solution on it.

My primary question is what is `debug_print_backtrace()` error and why its coming? and second is how can I remove it?

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree.  `debug_print_backtrace` is just what's *printing* the error, not what's *causing* it.  I've updated your question to make it more clear what the real problem is.

Comment: @Charles : Thanks but how can I remove it from my web page?

Comment: By *fixing the actual error*: a failed MySQL query.

Comment: @Charles : But my functionality is working correctly. Only it showing the above errors

Comment: Errors are *not* correct functionality.